# Eval in the div's background url

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net, webforms

I managed to eval link here

```
<div class="img-wrap" style='<%# "background: url('" + Eval("post_image") + "')  no-repeat; background-size:cover;" %>'>
```

But... I need yet direction to directory.. something like that

```
<div class="img-wrap" style='<%# "background: url('../images/" + Eval("post_image") + "')  no-repeat; background-size:cover;" %>'>
```

The problem is that it results with this kind of thing when I check it in browser

```
<div class="img-wrap" style="background: url(" ..="" images="" image-thumb.jpg')=""  no-repeat;=""   background-size:cover;'="">
```

It creates a spaces between and doesn't target to anything

@edit:

Here the img for better visualisation

[image](http://pasteboard.co/Xz4tn7T.png)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
style='<%# "background-image: url(../images/" + Eval("post_image") + ") no-repeat; background-size:cover;" %>'
```

Comment: Should work, but you probably need a `(string)` cast or a `.ToString()` call on the result of the `Eval`...